# Facebook PHP Graph Api POST working for some Users not for All (Detail in Description)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a App on Facebook its have 4500 Users.

What I do is Collect their Access_Token extend it and save it in my Database.

the Prob. is 1st I have made the code to Post it in PHP by using Graph Api it was posting but it crashed my Host because Grabbing Token from Mysql DB List of 4500 User & Then sending 1 by 1 Post on that user for 15 Min. My host was down.

Then I tried using JQuery Post like sending 1 Request in loop and it PHP file will do work by getting Post Variable, but its not working it Posted message on my Wall only other I have checked but no Result at all.

Here is Code:

```
if(isset($_POST['ctr'])){
$ctr=$_POST['ctr'];
$qu=mysql_query("Select access_token from fb");
echo (intval((mysql_num_rows($qu))/3));  

}else if(isset($_POST['ie'])){

$id=$_POST['ie'];

for($i=($id*3)-3;$i<$id*3;$i++){
$result=mysql_query("Select access_token from fb limit $i,1");

    if(isset($_POST['Desc'])){
$msg['description'] = $_POST['Desc'];
}

    //construct the message/post by posted data
    if(isset($_POST['message'])){
        $msg['message'] = $_POST['message'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['url']) && $_POST['url'] != 'http://'){
        $msg['link'] = $_POST['url'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['picture_url']) && $_POST['picture_url'] != ''){
        $msg['picture'] = $_POST['picture_url'];
    }


    if($result){

$msg['access_token'] = mysql_result($result,0);
            try {
                $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $msg);
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            }

        }}
```

JavaScript Code

```
function DooWork(){
sendit(0,1);




}

function sendit(mo,name)
{
   if(name==0){
  var get="ie="+mo+"&url="+document.getElementById('url').value+"&Desc="+document.getElementById('Desc').value+"&picture_url="+document.getElementById('purl').value+"&message="+document.getElementById('message').value;
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Admin.php",
    data: get,
    success: function(data) {


    }
  });
  }else{
  var get="ctr=0";
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Admin.php",
    data: get,
    success: function(data) {
 document.getElementById("Curr").innerHTML=data;
 dosomec(data);
    }
  });
  }


}

function dosomec(ml){

for(var i=1;i<=ml;i++){
sendit(i,0);

 document.getElementById("Text").innerHTML=ml;

}
}
```

What PHP code do is if Total rows is 4500 then do 4500/3 & after that send this vale to Javascript code using Ajax then it will loop and send

Any Help will be Really Appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I'm really not clear on what your problem is here

Comment: Could you explain this further, are you trying to post to 4500 users walls? are you trying to post to a page wall ?

Comment: @ShawnECarter Yes i am trying to Post on 4500 users wall

Igy the prob. is its Posting on wall Sometime not every time & i have checked the Access_token by Facebook Debug tool its not Expire and authenticated to that User

Comment: make sure that the user did not change default perms for your posting, i sometimes set apps to me only.  also make sure you are not posting to quickly, there should be a few second pause between posts.

Comment: @Shawn i have my app Installed on 2 Account on 1 its Posting but on 2nd Its not both are Show to Friends & yeah may be posting quickly will be a reason but when i send it on my account list 4-5 for checking its Posted without any prob. may be the prob. is in my JQuery code or in PHP Code .

Comment: keep in mind facebook 60/60 rule  basicly 60 requests per 60 seconds.  Lets say you post 300 messages in 5 minutes but 49 of those requests hang at the end around the 210, 230 mark and they finally post when you are on your 4th circuit around 240 to 280.  Now the next 5 or 300 posts run fine but the hung posts count for that block of 60/60 you just went over and it fail.s

Comment: now as per the 2 account:  it will be able to post to the account that created the token for that user.  if acct 1 created then acct 1 can posts unless each account is creating its own user token.

Comment: yeah i think 60/60 Rule may be a Prob. But what i did is made a Desktop Software in Vb.net so no PHP running time prob. & not Client Side (Javascript) Code prob. and its working fine i have used Graph API in Vb.net app it post a Request using the token which is grabbed via Mysql Connection 

Thanks Shawn & Igy for you valuable time reading this :)